# Best practises in case of possibly large requested file which is needed to be fully displayed

Tags: django, angular, angular-material

## The case

I am implementing a web app with Angular@6 and Django@2.2. In my app, I provide the users with a form with options. Based on the selected options, I request the backend for the relative results. The results are rows of the form {orderNumer: integer, message: string}. The number of rows, that the backend responds with, ranges from 0 up to 20k.

## The Problem and what I have done

I am currently using Angular Material Table, requesting the whole file from django (no streaming) and since angular get the results, I am passing them into angular material table.

The **problem** is that in case of 14k rows, the table displays this result with a delay of 12secs. I mean that from the time that all 14k rows are fetched to Angular from Django, there are 12 secs passed to be displayed.

## Some Limitations

I have noticed about pagination, i.e. requesting data in chunks either when user scrolls or gets to the results next page. However, this is not the desired behavior in my app. I want the user to be able to download the results without having to scroll down or getting to the next page again and again.

## Questions

What are some best practices in such a situation?

1) Do I partially load the results to angular material table? Is there a way?

2) What do I do while streaming the rows from the backend, instead of requesting the whole file? In this case, have I to do this independently of the size of the file?

Answer (score 0):

> What takes the most time is not downloading the array not even going through it. What takes 12sec is to add the HTML elements to the DOM.

So, this's what I would do in this situation:

- download the array (even if it's 14K rows, I don't think there's a need to stream it)
- Store a sub-array in a variable then display this sub-array with `ng-for-trackBy` for performance reasons (and add the code necessary to add rows as the user comes near the bottom of the displayed array)
- Use the OnPush change detection strategy, also for performance reasons (https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)

Or:

- Download the array
- Use a virtual scroll list by leveraging the Angular CDK (https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview)

Hope it helps,